# Struct Serialization using Unsafe Field

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to use structs as a container for data packets for asynchronous networking in C#. Found out that you can create a union style struct without the need to mark the struct itself as unsafe--instead marking the field as unsafe.

Example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 8, Pack = 4)]
struct DataPacketStruct {
    private unsafe fixed byte bytes[8];
    // Publicly accessible fields.
    public byte header;
    public int size;
    
    public void Serialize(ref byte[] buffer, int startIndex) {
        unsafe {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) buffer[startIndex + i] = bytes[i];
        }
    }

    public void Deserialize(byte[] buffer) {
        unsafe {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) bytes[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
    
    public int SizeOf() { unsafe { return sizeof(DataPacketStruct); } }
}
```

I know I need array out of bounds checking--but apart from that. Potential downsides or undefined behaviors? Or is this usage valid? Also are there any potential performance concerns or any alternatives with similar performance?

Also an issue I can see right off the bat is not having compile-time numeric constants like in C++. Unfortunately have to hard code in the field offsets and structure size because of this: `Size = 8` and `byte[8]`.

Comment: Afaik, .NET has enough powerful networking API that doesn't require any `unsafe` stuff. What's the purpose of the structure? Can you show and explain the usage example? `Explicit` structure can be needed for marshaling it to P/Invoke unmanaged function call e.g. send it as byte array. As option you may use `BinaryWriter` as managed alternative if you need just a byte array not P/Invoke.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-a-structure-to-a-byte-array-in-c)? Also consider `Buffer.BlockCopy` from `System.Buffers` as loop replacement.

Comment: @aepot it's a nice convenient way of creating packet data structures. You can write a byte stream to a struct and use the struct as a nice wrapper to represent your packet data.

Comment: @aepot no, but thank you I'll be using it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `safe` way to do that using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` ([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netframework-4.8)).

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 8, Pack = 4)]
struct DataPacketStruct
{
    public byte Header { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(byte[] buffer, int startIndex)
    {
        int size = SizeOf();
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, startIndex, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }

    public static DataPacketStruct Deserialize(byte[] buffer, int startIndex)
    {
        var result = new DataPacketStruct();
        int size = result.SizeOf();
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, startIndex, ptr, size);
        result = (DataPacketStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(DataPacketStruct));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return result;
    }

    public int SizeOf() => Marshal.SizeOf(this);
}
```

Also I used public properties and followed the [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) in the example.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = new DataPacketStruct() { Header = byte.MaxValue, Size = int.MaxValue };
    byte[] a = new byte[8];
    data.Serialize(a, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))));
    var data2 = DataPacketStruct.Deserialize(a, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data2, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
FF 00 00 00 FF FF FF 7F
{
  "Header": 255,
  "Size": 2147483647
}
```

Comment: Nice! I've seen this implementation using Marshal, problem is if you run a test on it, I bet it's not nearly as fast.

Comment: @FatalSleep there's no performance concern in the question above. Anyway, you may test it as you have the more real environment. In production environment I prefer something like JSON and HTTPS to transfer the data. It's more safe in terms of security. Writing network input directly to memory can be done only if you 100% trust the source. For socket-like data exchange i use WebSockets. That allows me to make browser client and desktop or mobile app clients using the same server.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly. I like the answer, but it doesn't really address the question, more so just says do it `safe`. Which, while I am using an unsafe methodology here, I did it in a specific manner to avoid having to mark the struct unsafe. Which normally one wouldn't do, but from a safety aspect not much is happening here IMO that is entirely problematic.

Comment: @FatalSleep Thank you for the feedback. I'm not sure that your way guarantee GC will not move the fields across the memory. You're making `unsafe` access to managed fields with no `fixed` directive which tells GC not to move that fields. That's why i can't confirm the correctness of your solution. By the first sight it looks suspicious. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: could you put that in your answer?

Comment: @FatalSleep i don't like put something to the answer if i'm not absolutely sure in that. I'm not.